# Clipping Polygons and creating a new polygon as a feature

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I am doing a task using the ArcPy module in ArcGIS Pro. The task is to Clip a polygon feature class with another polygon feature class and return the remaining polygons as a new feature class. I have to create a new toolbox for this task. I am looking for some ideas on how I should proceed. I tried to get help from some previous links but still looking for some hints.

This the code I have tried so far

```
inFeature1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inFeature2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    
listForNewFeatureClass = []
    
inFeature1Features = arcpy.Describe(inFeaturel).shapeFieldName
inFeature2Features = arcpy.Describe(inFeature2).shapeFieldName
    
searchCursor1 = arcpy.SearchCursor(inFeature1)
searchCursor2 = arcpy.SearchCursor(inFeature2)

for elements1 in searchCursor1:
    for elements2 in searchCursor2:
        pass
        # listForNewFeatureClass.append(name of your result variable)

newFC = arcpy.CreateFeatureclas_management(r'C:\SomePath', "POLYGON")

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newFC, ["SHAPE@XY"]) as insertCursor:
    for shape in listForNewFeatureClass:
        insertCursor.insertRow([shape])
```

Comment: The UI has a code button (`{}`), or you can use triple backtics above and below, but you've removed all the comments, and the indents are missing, so it's currently illegible.

Comment: Also there are curious spaces in the lines of codes, I guess pasting errors, you need to clean up your code as @Vince suggests so we can read it in the way you are attempting to run it.

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?  I recommend using new style cursors (e.g. `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`) rather than old (e.g. `arcpy.SearchCursor()`)

Comment: You are defining you newFC as POLYGON, yet your da.InsertCursor is set to SHAPE@XY which will only write a single X,Y coordinate. Look at using the SHAPE@ to insert geometry